# Divi Child Theme not appearing in "Themes"

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, troubleshooting

I've created a "divi-child" folder within the "/themes" directory of my site with the appropriate "style.css" and "functions.php" files within. Code for those files is below. Even with all of this in place it seems as though, from my extensive searching, that my child theme should be showing up on my "Themes" dashboard, but it is not there.

I've been trying to fix this for the past few hours any help?

I'm new to child themes so I apologize for my ignorance.

EDIT 10-23-17 | For some reason my answer was deleted...Go figure ("Moderators"). There's no answer to this problem other than I messed up my FTP/SFTP settings, so I was editing in one server, but seeing another. That simple. Don't know why someone deleted the only answer to this haha. But, thanks again to everyone else who tried to help!

**STYLE.CSS**

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Divi Child
 Description:  Divi Child Theme
 Author:       Reach|Impress
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     Divi
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
```

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

Comment: try to put the exact directory name for the parent name, e.g. `Template: divi` in order to respect name case

Comment: For some reason my answer was deleted...Go figure. There's no answer to this problem other than I messed up my FTP/SFTP settings, so I was editing in one place, but seeing the other. That simple. Don't know why someone delete the only answer to this lol. But, thanks again to everyone else who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

The template name when declaring a parent in a child theme's CSS is case sensitive. Try changing the line to:

```
Template:    divi
```

Comment: The actual directory is "Divi" for the parent. I've tried it both ways in the css field and still nothing. I'm starting to think a plug-in or something is keeping wordpress cached in a way that it isn't loading that directory. I don't have a caching plug-in activated, but is it possible for Wordfence to mess that up?

Comment: The best way to find out if there are any compatibility issues is by deactivating all plugins, and seeing if it works. If it does, reactivate them one by one to see which is causing an issue.

Comment: On a side note, a child theme looks for the defined `Text Domain:` value in the parent theme's `style.css` to decide its parent. Not the directory name.

Comment: No luck on deactivating all plug-ins. What if the parent `style.css` does not contain that variable?

Comment: Have you tried the Divi Child Theme builder?
https://divi.space/divi-child-theme-builder/

Comment: I tried that link you sent me, created a child theme, uploaded it, and activated it. It seems to be working, but when I go to my ftp and try to find the folder for that child theme I don't see it under the "Themes" directory!!!